# How to fill my lib folder from jar files located in different svn repositories?

Tags: java, svn, version-control, jar, svn-externals

I have structured my jave project as:

```
MyProejct
  - src
  - build
  - test
  - lib
  - ..
```

In the root of my lib folder, I've placed all of my external .jar files (hibernate, jboss, etc). Now I have decided to move all my third-party jar files into another repo (Namely Lib) and have them on my lib folder while checking out the project. I've used svn:externals to do this. I have created my Lib repo like the following:

```
Lib Repository
  - hibernate
  - jsf
  - junit
  - ...
```

Why when I refer these jar files using svn:external property to different folders in my Lib repo, only .jar files in my last external property are checked out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to have many files in a folder coming from different repositories using externals. The best way to do this is to keep each .jar file in its own folder and update the content of that folder by its relevant external property.

Answer (score 0):

svn:externals is **versioned property**, thus, you get files, which correlate to the state of svn:externals for **current revision of Working Copy**

Comment: So, how can I collect all of my .jar files located in different repos into a single folder?

Comment: @hsalimi - you have now all files (physically) in lib, as I read your text. Which **additional externals** you want to have? In case of SVN 1.6, you can use externals on file-level and define or skip PEG-revision of external resource